# UIApplication and _powerDown method...Where?

Tags: iphone, tweak

i saw on github a project where the developer used the method _powerDown to powerOff the iPhone or relaunchSpringBoard to respring it.The line of code is this:

```
[[UIApplication SharedApplication]_powerDown];
```

but i was searching this method on the class reference of UIApplication but i didn't find it...Could anyone help me?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this really is a method of `UIApplication`, but if it is, it is definitely a private one. Therefore it is not listed in the official documentation and you should not us it.

Comment: so i can't see the private methods?even if i'm developing an app not for the appstore?